# Iterate in Keras custom loss function

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I know that is better avoid loop in `Keras` custom loss function, but I think I have to do it.
The problem is the following: I'm trying to implement a loss function that compute a loss value for multiple bunches of data and then aggregate this values in an unique value.

For example I have 6 data entry, so in my `Keras` loss I'll have 6 `y_true` and 6 `y_pred`.
I want to compute 2 loss value: one for the first 3 elements and one for the last 3 elements.

Example of hypothetical code:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred): 
    start_range = 0
    losses = []
    for index in range(0,2):
        end_range = start_range + 3
        y_true_bunch = y_true[start_range:end_range]
        y_pred_bunch = y_pred[start_range:end_range]
        loss_value = ...some processing on bunches...
        losses.append(loss_value)
        start_range = end_range
    final_loss = ...aggregate loss_value...
    return final_loss
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this without `for` loop? I need to process the whole dataset and calculate loss for multiple bunches and then aggregate all bunches value in a single value.

Comment: Hi. This question is more appropriate for Stack Overflow because this is just a programming issue. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details. I will migrate it to SO.